# Springsourcetoolsuite Issue

Tags: spring-roo, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I was trying this springroo quick sample on how to build an app on THE STS i.e springsourcetoolsuite..
Maven keeps complaining of this errors. I am really confused. I am using SpringSource Tool Suite Version: 2.5.2.RELEASE.

```
3/10/11 1:09:54 PM VET: Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.6.0.Final:compile
3/10/11 1:09:54 PM VET: Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.2.0.Final:compile
3/10/11 1:09:54 PM VET: Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.6.0.Final:compile
3/10/11 1:09:54 PM VET: Missing artifact javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.0.GA:compile
3/10/11 1:09:54 PM VET: Missing artifact org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
3/10/11 1:09:54 PM VET: Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.1.0.Final:compile
3/10/11 1:09:54 PM VET: Missing artifact javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
```

Please has anyone resolved this issue? I really need help

I have resolved the issues above the errors where due to wrong version number of the jars so i added the recent jars.so i changed them to reflect the latest and the error has moved to the "400" error code cos it can't resolve the url anyways can i get the correct version
    
                
                    spring-maven-release
                    Spring Maven Release Repository
                    http://maven.springframework.org/release
                
                
                    spring-maven-milestone
                    Spring Maven Milestone Repository
                    http://maven.springframework.org/milestone
                
                
                    spring-roo-repository
                    Spring Roo Repository
                    http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release

Comment: I have resolve this issues. The version numbers of the jars were not the lastest aand were not present .Now  I have errors because of that find this  repo links does have the correct links or is the server down?

Answer (score 0):

Get the location of your local maven repo is. From repo delete the last updated file that maven keeps in your repo for the corresponding artifacts that are missing, if you don't see any jars in that folder. Following this update all your maven dependencies from eclipse and see if the jars are getting downloaded.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have resolved the issues above the errors where due to wrong version number of the jars so i added the recent jars.so i changed them to reflect the latest and the error has moved to the "400" error code cos it can't resolve the url anyways can i get the correct version spring-maven-release Spring Maven Release Repository http://maven.springframework.org/release spring-maven-milestone Spring Maven Milestone Repository http://maven.springframework.org/milestone spring-roo-repository Spring Roo Repository http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release

Comment: Do you see the lastupdated file? And are the jars present in the respective folder? If not then your maven installation is not able to connect/download the right jars for you from the remote location. try connecting the the maven repo through browser and downlod the jar directly if you don't see any downloaded jars.

Comment: I saw the lastupdated files but no jars present. please can i have the url of the maven repo. and when i do download them does maven immediately recognize them. pardon me its the third time in a long time using maven. i have ben using ANT most of the while

Comment: Try this stackoverflow thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013576/maven-is-failing-to-download-the-tomcat-maven-plugin-snapshot